# How to combine child FormGroup with parent FormGroup in Angular

Tags: angular

I am working with angular8 to create a customer, basically create customer requires customer details and trip details.

So I created a CreateCustomer and trip components, inside create customer Injecting trip component. From trip component I am creating a form group for trip and used inside the trip html and whenever the trip form changes I am emitting the trip form to parent using Eventemitter.

In Customer component I am trying to add that trip form-group to provide input to create service call. I am getting following issue when changes happen in trip.

```
core.js:6185 ERROR TypeError: control.setParent is not a function
    at FormGroup.registerControl (forms.js:5071)
    at FormGroup.setControl (forms.js:5120)
```

This is my parent component

```
export class CreateCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,  private createService: CreateService, private router: Router) {
    }

    customerForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      address: ['', Validators.required],
      contact_name: [{value: '', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      contact_email: [{value: '', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      phone: [{value: '', disabled: true}]
    });

    //Here I am trying to add child form group to parent formgroup
    tripFormChangeEvent (tripFormGroup: FormGroup) {
      this.customerForm.addControl('trip',tripFormGroup);
    }

    onSubmit() {
    this.createService.create(this.customerForm)
      .subscribe(data => {
        if (data["success"]) {
          alert("Created Successfuly..!")
        }
      });
    }
}
```

Parent HTML,

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 form-group">
  <label for="txtName">Customer</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtName" class="form-control" formControlName="name" required>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Required
  </div>
</div>

<app-trip (onFormGroupChange)="tripFormChangeEvent($event)"></app-trip>
```

Child Component

```
export class TripComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() onFormGroupChange = new EventEmitter<FormGroup>();

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  tripForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    cityStateZip: [''],
    pickup_date: [''],
    pickup_time: [''],
    notes: ['']
  })

  ngOnInit() {
    this.onValueChanges();
  }

  onValueChanges(): void {
    this.tripForm.valueChanges.pipe( debounceTime(1000)).subscribe(val=>{
      this.onFormGroupChange.emit(this.tripForm.value);
    })
  }

}
```

Child HTML,

```
<div class="border p-2 mb-2" [formGroup]="tripForm">
<legend  class="w-auto small font-weight-bold">Trip NAme</legend>
<div class="form-row pb-sm-3">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 form-group">
      <label for="txtOrigName">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrigName" class="form-control" formControlName="name" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Required
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your solution, hopefully will fix

No need of Formgroup to be emit without a specific requirement. In your case, there is nothing

Create your trip formgroup inside Create component

```
export class CreateCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,  private createService: CreateService, private router: Router) {
    }

    customerForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      address: ['', Validators.required],
      contact_name: [{value: '', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      contact_email: [{value: '', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      phone: [{value: '', disabled: true}],    
    tripForm: this.fb.group({
        name: ['', Validators.required],
        cityStateZip: [''],
        pickup_date: [''],
        pickup_time: [''],
        notes: ['']
        }),
    });

    //Here I am trying to add child form group to parent formgroup
    tripFormChangeEvent (tripFormGroup: FormGroup) {
      this.customerForm.addControl('trip',tripFormGroup);
    }

    onSubmit() {
    this.createService.create(this.customerForm)
      .subscribe(data => {
        if (data["success"]) {
          alert("Created Successfuly..!")
        }
      });
    }
}
```

Parent HTML,

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 form-group">
  <label for="txtName">Customer</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtName" class="form-control" formControlName="name" required>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Required
  </div>
</div>

<app-trip [customerForm]="customerForm"></app-trip>
```

Child Component

```
export class TripComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() customerForm : FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Child HTML,

```
<div class="border p-2 mb-2" [formGroup]="customerForm">
<legend  class="w-auto small font-weight-bold">Trip NAme</legend>
<div class="form-row pb-sm-3" formGroupName="tripForm">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3 form-group">
      <label for="txtOrigName">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="txtOrigName" class="form-control" formControlName="name" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Required
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error happen because `addControl` assume you pass in `formControl` but you pass in JSON value. your child component emit form value instead of `FormGroup`, your parent component `tripFormChangeEvent` define parameter as `FormGroup` too, change your child component emit to `this.onFormGroupChange.emit(this.tripForm)`.